# Loading texture for OpenGL with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, textures

I have seen many code samples for loading textures for **OpenGL**, many of them a bit complicated to understand or requiring new functions with a lot of code.

I was thinking that as **OpenCV** allows us to load any image format it can be a simple an efficient way to load textures to **OpenGL**, but I am missing something. I have this piece of code in **c++**:

```
cv::Mat texture_cv;
GLuint texture[1];
int Status=FALSE;

if( texture_cv = imread("stones.jpg"))  {

        Status=TRUE;                            // Set The Status To TRUE
        glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);                  // Create The Texture


        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);               
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
        glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S , GL_REPEAT );
        glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture_cv.cols, texture_cv.rows, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_cv.data);
}
```

And it is not compiling because of this error:

> error C2451: conditional expression of type 'cv::Mat' is illegal

Any suggestions? How should I do the conversion from cv::Mat to openGL texture?

Comment: I think that using OpenCV for loading textures is overkill. There's the library DevIL which has been designed explicitly for this.

Comment: I am using OpenCV in my project and I am constantly changing from opengl to opencv data, that's why I got the idea of reducing libraries. Thanks anyway for the DevIL, I will have look at it.

Comment: FreeImage is also another (more recent) alternative to DevIL =)

Comment: Should that not be `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE` if `texture.cols != texture.rows` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error appears there, right?

```
if( texture_cv = imread("stones.jpg"))  {
```

because in `if(expr)` expr must be `bool` or can be casted to `bool`. But there is no way to convert `cv::Mat` into boolean implicitly. But you can check the result of `imread` like that:

```
texture_cv = imread("stones.jpg");
if (texture_cv.empty()) {
  // handle was an error
} else {
  // do right job
}
```

See: [cv::Mat::empty()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#cv-mat-empty), [cv::imread](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imread)

Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment operator

```
texture_cv = imread("stones.jpg")
```

returns a `cv::Mat` that can't be used in a conditional expression. You should write something like

```
if((texture_cv = imread("stones.jpg")) != /* insert condition here */ )  {
      //...
}
```

or

```
texture = imread("stone.jpg");
if(!texture.empty())  {
          //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) doc, I suggest you to change your test:

```
texture_cv = imread("stones.jpg");
if (texture_cv.data != NULL)  {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short question...
I think you may need to use

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture_cv.cols, texture_cv.rows, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_cv.ptr());
```

instead of

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture_cv.cols, texture_cv.rows, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_cv.data);
```