# Convert OpenGL texture to OpenCV Mat

Tags: opengl, opencv, typeconverter

Is there any way to convert OpenGL's `GLuint texture` type to OpenCV's `cv::Mat` ?

Comment: I have got just the oposite function, texture2opencvMat, if you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/q/9126002/744859

Answer (score 6):

You may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9097756/743214) which asks about converting from `glReadPixels` into a `cv::Mat`, which is exactly the same problem when using [`glGetTexImage`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml) instead of `glReadPixels`.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098883/743214) to this question explains how to directly read the texture data into the `cv::Mat`'s storage with all possible pitfalls (like padding, color ordering, ...).